# RelativeLayout.params getRule before API23

Tags: android

I'm trying to check a rule in RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, but getRule() was only introduced in API 23, is there a way to do this in the earlier versions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is another method similar to `getRule()` called `getRules()`, which was introduced in API Level 1. The documentation for the method is at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#getRules(). You can use this method similarly. Instead of passing the `int`, you pass nothing and get an array of supported rules. You can then loop through that array of rules and compare them with the rule you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
int[] rules = relativeLayout.LayoutParams.getRules();
for(int rule : rules) {
    if(rule == rule1 || rule == rule2 || rule == rule3) {
        // Rule exists in RelativeLayout
    } else {
        // Rule doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay this makes sense, but I want to check if the rule ALIGN_TOP with a specific view is present, with getRule() I could do it like this `if (params.getRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP) == R.id.mView)` how do I do it with this method?

Comment: You could do `if(rule == R.id.dois_3)`. Since it is looping through all the rules of the `relativeLayout`, it will check if the two `int`  variables match (`R.id.dois_3` is an `int`) .

Comment: Is there a way to use this method withuot a for loop? With a for loop it executes the `else{...}` one time for every rule it has

Comment: You have to use this with a loop because you need to check all values in the array to see if they match up. If you don't want the `else` statement being executed you could just remove that whole loop and use a one line `if` statement, like so: `if(rule == yourRule) /* INSERT HERE */;`, or you could just remove the `else` statement.

Comment: The problem is I need to execute code if the rule == myRule and a diffrent code if rule != myRule, but each one only once, is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to execute one of those two conditions just stick with the if/else statement, because the `else` gets executed if `rule != yourRule`

Comment: The following situation is what is happening: I have 3 rules, the 3rd one is myRule so the `rule != myRule` code gets executed twice and then the `rule == myRule` gets executed. What I need is: I have 3 rules, the 3rd one is myRule, if any of the rules is myRule `code1` gets executed, if none of the 3 rules is myRule then only `code2` gets executed

Comment: The for loop still executes once for every rule that exists, executing either the `code1` or the `code2`

Comment: rule == rule1 does not work, because rules is an array of 0 and -1 (RelativeLayout.TRUE). In order to check if a rule exists you should directly index the array, i.e. rules[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM] != 0 . See @Mohit Singh answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's an easier way to do this. You need not loop through the rules as described in AkashBhave's answer.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rl.getLayoutParams();
```

Any rule can be easily accessed like this:

```
params.getRules()[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP]
```

And for your use case (as mentioned by you in the comments above), you can do this:

```
if(params.getRules()[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP] == R.id.mView){

}
```

Also, in case you just wish to check whether a particular rule exists:

```
if(params.getRules()[RelativeLayout.ABOVE] == 0){
   //it does not
} else {
   //it does
}
```